# Sion's MinMax theorem over matrices

Tags: general-topology, optimization, game-theory

Suppose $A\in R^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, i.e., $A>0$. Can we apply Sion's theorem to conclude the following:

$\underset{Y\in R^{n\times n}}{\min}\underset{X\in \mathcal{S}}{\max} \text{Trace}(YAY^T+YXY^T)=\underset{X\in \mathcal{S}}{\max}\underset{Y\in R^{n\times n}}{\min}\text{Trace}(YAY^T+YXY^T)$

where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of all positive definite matrices? How about if $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of all positive semi-definite matrices?

Comment: Are there any transposes missing or are you assuming $Y$ to be symmetric by any chance?

Comment: I edited and added the transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(Y,B):=\text{Tr}(YBY^T)\ge0$ for all positive semi-definite $B$. $f(0,B)=0$. So $\min_{Y\in R^{n\times n}}f(Y,B)=0$ for every $B$. Therefore both sides of your desired equation are $0$ and thus the equation holds. There is no need for Sion's theorem. Besides, the premise of Sion's theorem is not satisfied as $R^{n\times n}$ is not compact.

Comment: For Sion's theorem we only need for one of the sets to be compact.

Comment: My questions here will be whether $X\geq 0$, $X\in R^{n\times n}$ is homeomorphic to the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$ for an arbitrary norm

Comment: @EricBrown: Yes, the homeomorphism exists but then you need to map infinity onto the shell of the ball to close the set. Once you do that, do you still have the semi-concavity and semi-convexity?

Comment: I think I used a bad example for my question. What I was wondering was more like: Can we apply Sion's theorem to conclude the following:

$\underset{Y\in R^{n\times n}}{\min}\underset{X\in \mathcal{S}}{\max} f(X,Y)=\underset{X\in \mathcal{S}}{\max}\underset{Y\in R^{n\times n}}{\min}f(X,Y)$
where $f$ is concave in X and convex in $Y$, and $\mathcal{S}=\{X\in R^{n\times n}| \|X\|\leq 1\}$. Here $\|Y\|$ is the spectral norm of matrix Y.

Comment: @EricBrown: Well yes, but is it not just Sion's theorem directly?

Comment: To apply the Sion theorem here we need to show $\mathcal{S}$ is homeomorphic to a compact and convex set in $R^{n^2}$. How can we show this? Would $\mathcal{S}$ be compact and convex if $\|X\|<1$?

Comment: @EricBrown: Of course, any bounded and closed set in $R^n$ for finite $n$ is compact. Your $<$ or open ball should be replaced by $\le$ or closed ball. Do you need the proof of convexity of $\|X\|\le1$?

Comment: I think I know how to prove the convexity. Here $X\in R^{n\times n}$ is a matrix. I just want to know how to show that set of matrices that satisfy $\|X\|\leq1$ is homeomorphic to a compact and convex set in $R^{n^2}$ (vector space).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71882/discussion-between-hans-and-eric-brown).

Comment: @EricBrown: If you know how to show the convexity, and I have told you how to prove compactness, you are all set.

Comment: Convexity can be shown as follows: consider $\|X_1\|\leq 1$ and $\|X_2\|\leq 1$. Then $\|\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda)X_2\|\leq \lambda\|X_1\|+(1-\lambda)\|X_2\|\leq \lambda+(1-\lambda)=1$, for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @EricBrown: Then you, as I said, are all set and have no more problem with this question. Do you agree? I just don't see why you keep referring to a homeomorphism. The closed ball $\|X\|\le1$ IS a compact and convex set already under the topology defined by the norm.

Comment: The reason I am using homeomorphism is because this question is asked in the context of optimization problem whose decision variables should live in vector space, rather than matrix space. So to use Sion's theorem, I think we should prove convex and compactness in vector space. I am not a mathematician, so I would appreciate it if you correct me.

Comment: @EricBrown: I see. That explains the apparent slight confusion here. The homeomorphism here is the trivial one, as $R^{m\times n}$ IS a (abstract) vector space since it satisfies the definition of one. More concretely, you can simply reshape or unravel an $m\times n$ matrix  into a column one of size $(m\times n)\times1$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would need Sion' minmax theorem to prove this.

Note that the max on the left-hand side when fixing $Y\neq 0$ is $+\infty$ as the objective is linear in $X$ and $Y^TY\succeq 0$. The left-hand side is only bounded for $Y=0$, so the left-hand side is 0.

Now let's look at the right-hand side: $Tr(AB) \geq 0$, when $A$ and $B$ are PSD. So the min on the right-hand side should be 0, which is achieved at $Y=0$, regardless of X. So the right-hand side is also 0.